# JavaScript - Como comparo estos dos horarios?

Tags: javascript, html, script

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación conectada a una API.
La API me devuelve un valor de tipo String IGUAL a esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito hacer es imprimir esa fecha y hora, pero con horario GMT-3.
Es decir, obtener event_date y despues imprimirlo, en este caso, como: **2020-08-19 17:30hs**
Y, si es posible, acomodarle la fecha a: **19-08-2020**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar lo que pedís, podes crear un objeto del tipo `Date` y asignarle esa fecha, por ejemplo:

```
let fecha = new Date("2020-08-19T20:30:00+00:00")
```

Si queres mostrar la fecha con el formato DD/MM/AAAA podes acceder a los métodos del objeto Date y armar el string, por ejemplo:

```
console.log(`${fecha.getDate()}-${fecha.getMonth() + 1}-${fecha.getFullYear()}`)
```

Comment: Y como bajaria la variable fecha a GMT-3?

Comment: ya esta en formato GMT-3, proba de hacer console.log(fecha) y ahi lo comprobas. Es la hora estandar de Argentina

Comment: agregue un + 1 en el mes porque getMonth() devuelve un numero entre 0 y 11

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la librería [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) la cual te ayuda a manejar las zonas horarias y los formatos de manera sencilla.

Por ejemplo elegimos las zonas horarias disponibles [aqui](https://gist.github.com/diogocapela/12c6617fc87607d11fd62d2a4f42b02a)

```js
var date = moment("2020-08-19T20:30:00+00:00").zone("Etc/GMT-3");

console.log("date",date.format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm"))
console.log("date",date.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```